# I failed trying to uninstall ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I wanted to uninstall ubuntu from my computer. I didn't know how to so I tried to just delete the Ubuntu segment from my Disk Management window. I deleted it and now it just stays there as unallocated space. I can't seem to fix it by extending the volume on my windows disk because it says "There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation". How can I fix this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVTgh.png)

Comment: Please add which partition was previously assigned to Ubuntu. Is this a single disk or you have attached some external hard drive?

Comment: I assigned E to Ubuntu but now the assigned part is unallocated because I deleted the Ubuntu(I know it was a stupid thing to do but I didn't know how to remove it)

Comment: As far as I know, according to the screenshot provided your Disk1 is dynamic. Try deleting all the partitions and creating a whole new Basic Partition(if there is no operating system is in Disk 1 since it has an EFI partition).

Comment: That will be tough since it is almost full but thanks anyway I might try that once I back those up

Answer (score 0):

Boot into gparted live usb (https://gparted.org/liveusb.php) or insert Ubuntu iso usb that has gparted installed.

Using gparted, ensure the 22GB partition and the 512MB are unmounted - (appears these are the ones you want deleted). Select 22 GB partition and select delete. Repeat this action for the 512 MB partition.

Select the apply button in the top pane of gparted. Gparted will prompt you that operations are complete.

Reboot your device. Using Disk Management tool, extend the partitions to create one large partition. If by chance DM won't extend the partition, use gparted in a live session again to extend the partition.

Have fun

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are there any other alternative to gparted because it doesn't work on my computer. (After I enter gparted live its stuck with some words and a dark background)

Comment: Go to gparted forum for help with your issue http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/